# Python3 парсер с помощью grab

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, grab

Наблюдаю проблему с парсером сайта.

```
import re
import sys
import pars

from grab import Grab #импортируем граб для работы с парсингом

url = pars.s.pop()

#url = 'http://www.newsvl.ru/society/2016/11/06/153268/'

xpath = ('//div[@class="story__text"]')

print(url)

g = Grab()
g.go(url)

try:
    print(g.doc.select(xpath).text())
except IndexError:
    print('not found')
```

Вот такой вариант не работает:

```
http://www.newsvl.ru/society/2016/11/06/153268/
not found
```

Но если раскомментировать строчку

```
url = 'http://www.newsvl.ru/society/2016/11/06/153268/'
```

То все работает — текст выводится . 
Ссылка по pars.s.pop() приходит рабочая. (выводится принтом)
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

С помощью grab не удалось решить этот вопрос. Подключил библиотеку BeautifulSoup и там все заработало.